# Send modified table to controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table with data in an ASP.NET MVC View.What I want to do is the user to be able to change the data in the table and by pressing a button to send the new data to the controller. I need to get the innerHTML data that the user is modifying in the table and send that data through an AJAX call to the controller method.

The problem is that the table is dynamically generated in a Razor view and to be able get the innerHTML of a tag I need to know the `id` of the element that the user modified. As it's dynamically generated, I do not know that id, so I cannot just use jQuery and extract the data from the HTML tags.

The only solution that I thought would work would be to open a new page with a new formular and the user to be able to modify the data there, but I would not want to use this solution to create a new formular and a redirect to another page.

Another solution that I thought of would be to create a button which calls a Javascript function on click that takes all the innerHTML data from the table and sends it back to the controller. The controller then verifies each row in the database and if it is modified it updates the database. That would be a lot of work and I do not know if it would actually work.

I added the view that I'm working on here:

```html
@using Models;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@{
    var lstBID = ViewBag.BIDList as IEnumerable<BID>;
    int[] j = lstBID.Select(id => id.Id).ToArray();
    string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j);

}

@model Models.BID

<head>
  <script>
    var arr = @s;

    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log(arr);

      var BID = {
        Id: $("#Id").html(),
        Price: $("#Price").html(),
        Quantity: $("#Quantity").html()
      }

      $("#bidupdate").click(function() {
        console.log("Hello")
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/User/UpdateBID",
          data: BID,
          cache: false,
          async: true,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
          },
        });
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>
<html>

<body>
  <div style="width:100% ;padding-right:30%; float :left">
    <table id="verticalScroll" class="table-editable table table-light table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>
            ID
          </th>
          <th>
            CompanyName
          </th>
          <th>
            Price
          </th>
          <th>
            Quantity
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        @foreach (BID b in lstBID) {
          <tr>
            <td id="Id_@b.Id">
              @b.Id
            </td>
            <td>
              @b.CompanyName
            </td>
            <td id="Price_@b.Id" contenteditable="true">
              @b.Price
            </td>
            <td id="Quantity_@b.Id" contenteditable="true">
              @b.Quantity
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" value="Details" class="btn btn-primary" id="@b.Id">Update</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `id` attributes in HTML which you create in a loop. This is because `id` attributes need to be unique. Use common classes instead. Then you can find the elements related to the button which was clicked by traversing the DOM to retrieve the nearest common `tr` and calling `find()` from there.

Note that if you want a single button to retrieve the data for the entire table then that can be done quite easily by using `map()`.

See example of both of these techniques in the example below:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".update-row").on('click', function() {
    let $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    let data = {
      id: $row.find('.id').text().trim(),
      companyName: $row.find('.companyname').text().trim(),
      price: $row.find('.price').text().trim(),
      quantity: $row.find('.quantity').text().trim(),
    }

    console.log(data);

    /* commented out only for this example, as it won't work in a snippet...
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/User/UpdateBID",
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
    */
  });

  $('.send-all').on('click', function() {
    let data = $('#verticalScroll tr').map(function() {
      let $row = $(this);
      return {
        id: $row.find('.id').text().trim(),
        companyName: $row.find('.companyname').text().trim(),
        price: $row.find('.price').text().trim(),
        quantity: $row.find('.quantity').text().trim(),
      }
    }).get();
    
    // send data in an AJAX request here... 
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table id="verticalScroll" class="table-editable table table-light table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>CompanyName</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="id">1</td>
        <td class="companyname">Foo bar</td>
        <td class="price" contenteditable="true">1.99</td>
        <td class="quantity" contenteditable="true">10</td>
        <td><button type="button" value="Details" class="btn btn-primary update-row">Update</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="id">2</td>
        <td class="companyname">Fizz buzz</td>
        <td class="price" contenteditable="true">10.50</td>
        <td class="quantity" contenteditable="true">2</td>
        <td><button type="button" value="Details" class="btn btn-primary update-row">Update</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<button class="send-all">Send all data</button>
```